# Como usar o selenium para selecionar uma tag específica com uma classe comum a outras tags?

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Eu to querendo fazer scrapping dos dados mais atualizados desta [página](https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/preco_horario). Todos os dias ela disponibiliza os dados do dia atual e do dia seguinte. Meu maior interesse é nos dados do dia seguinte. Ao inspecionar as tags do calendário (Que é uma tabela), se observa que todas as datas disponíveis (A do dia seguinte e as dos dias anteriores) tem a classe  "available". A tag do dia atual por outro lado tem (além da classe available) as classes "active, today, start-date e end-date". Ou seja, só a tag do dia atual é única e fácil de ser obter e de ser "clicada". Só que preciso dar um click na tag referente ao dia seguinte a da tag atual. Pensei em usar a tag do dia atual como referência para pegar a tag seguinte, mas além de não achar um jeito pra fazer isso, cheguei a conclusão que pegar a tag seguinte daria erro quando o dia atual fosse o último dia da semana e tag td de interesse estivesse dentro da tr de baixo.

Trecho de interesse do código da página:

```
<tr>
    <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">7</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r1c1">8</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r1c2">9</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r1c3">10</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r1c4">11</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r1c5">12</td>
    <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c6">13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="today weekend active start-date active end-date available" data- 
    title="r2c0">14</td>
    <td class="available" data-title="r2c1">15</td>
    <td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c2">16</td>
    <td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c3">17</td>
    <td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c4">18</td>
    <td class="off disabled" data-title="r2c5">19</td>
    <td class="weekend off disabled" data-title="r2c6">20</td>
</tr>
```

Esse é o código em python que estou construindo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import  sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.headless = True
url = 'https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/preco_horario'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=option)
driver.get(url)
sleep(8)
#click para abrir o calendário
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='datefilterHorarioGrafico']//input[@id='datefilterHorarioGrafico']").click()
sleep(2)
#click para selecionar o dia
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr//td[@class='available']").click()
```

Espero que possam me ajudar. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como consegui resolver sozinho, vou postar aqui.

Há um parâmetro do selenium para você filtrar pelo conteúdo contido na tag. O código fica:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr//td[@class='available' and contains(text(), 'CONTEÚDO')]]").click()
```

Neste caso, como o interesse é obter o dia seguinte, supondo que o scrapping seja feito no dia 14, o código fica:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr//td[@class='available' and contains(text(), '15')]]").click()
```